# Monitor Setting in Registry in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-registry

When we want to change the display setting, we can use the display setting UI.

But besides UI, can I directly change the setting in the registry so that I can programmatically do it?

For instance, I want to switch between "Duplicate these displays" and "Show desktop only on 1" via code.

How could I do so?

Comment: It is possible to create a batch file that will read a key in the registry, and if its 1, make it 0, else it will make it 1. I don't know that there is a registry key for this though.

Comment: Not sure about registry, but [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/changing-display-settings.aspx?msg=3480919) shows how to change display settings programmatically.